# No agrega el atributo del la clase hija en datagridview c#

Tags: c#, .net

estoy teniendo problemas con el DataGridView, no esta tomando el atributo de la clase hija, los atributos de la clase padre los muestra correctamente.
Esta es la clase Padre

```
public abstract class Electrodomestico
{
public string Nombre { get; set; }
public bool Encendido { get;}
public abstract int Consumo();
}
}
```

Clase hija

```
class Heladera : Electrodomestico
{
public int CapacidadLitros{ get; set; }
public int ConsumoWatt = 350;
public override int Consumo()
{
if (CapacidadLitros <= 500){
ConsumoWatt = 300;
return ConsumoWatt;
}
return ConsumoWatt;
}
            
    
}
}
```

Aca estoy creando el objeto y cargando el objeto

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
RedElectrica red = new RedElectrica();
List<Electrodomestico> el = new List <Electrodomestico>();
el.Add(new Heladera() { CapacidadLitros = 1000, Nombre="Helader"});*/
el.Add(new Heladera() { CapacidadLitros = 1000 , Nombre = "Heladera" });
el.Add(new Televisor() { Pulgadas = 40, Nombre = "Tele" });
red.Agregar(new Televisor() { Pulgadas = 40 });
dataGridView1.DataSource = el;
cargar();
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que datos se supone que no esta tomando???

Comment: Ah espera.. tu lista es de tipo Electrodomestico... entonces no sabe que lo que ingresaste son hijos.. solo ve objetos de tipo Electrodomestico....

Comment: Como te dice @gbianchi, la lista es de tipo `Electrodomestico` por lo que no te va a importar mas que los atributos de esa clase, los objetos padre no heredan los atributos de los hijos sino al revés, los hijos heredan los del padre, creo que estas planteando mal la lógica de lo que estas intentando hacer

Answer (score 1):

muy interesante tu publicacion.
Primero que todo, una clase hija si puede heredar las propiedades de la clase padre pero una clase padre no puede heredar o ser tratada como una instancia de la clase hija, que es lo que estas tratando de hacer.

una posible solucion seria crear una lista de objetos `List<object> el = new List<object>();` pero eso no serviria  para tu proposito ya que todas las clases tendrian atributos diferentes y cuando los pasas  al datagrid view no podria organizar las columnas por lo tanto arrojaria una excepcion.

La mejor solucion o la mas logica seria crear una interface "IElecttodomestico" en vez de una clase abstracta y hacer que todas la clases hereden de la misma interface y por lo tanto estarian obligadas a implementar cada propiedad y metodo aunque no tendrian que initializar la propiedad cuando se crea la instancia de la clase. por ejemplo la clase Heladera no necesita la propiedad Pulgadas y tendria como valor 0 para ese atributo.

Cada campo que quieras que aparezca en el datagridview tendrias que declararla en la interface y implementarla en cada clase heredera.

Tu codigo se veria algo asi:

```
public interface IElectrodomestico
    {
        string Nombre { get; set; }
        int Consumo { get; set; }
        int CapacidadLitros { get; set; }
        int Pulgadas { get; set; }
        bool Encendido { get; set; }

        int CalcularConsumo();
    }
```

y para la clase:

```
   class Heladera : IElectrodomestico
    {
        public int CapacidadLitros { get; set; }
        public int ConsumoWatt = 350;
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        //Observacion:  podria solo tener un valor de retorno. ej: get{return ConsumoWatt}
        public int Consumo { get; set; }
        //esta propiedad no es necesaria pero la clase esta obligada a implementarla
        public int Pulgadas { get; set; }
        public bool Encendido { get; set; }
        //calcular el consumo y pasar el resultado a la propiedad Consumo
        public   int CalcularConsumo()
        {
            if (CapacidadLitros <= 500)
            {
                ConsumoWatt = 300;
                return ConsumoWatt;
            }
            return ConsumoWatt;
        }
    }
```

Otra clase que implemente IElectrodomestico:

```
 class Televisor : IElectrodomestico
    {
        public int Pulgadas { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public bool Encendido { get; set; }
        //Observacion:  podria solo tener un valor de retorno. ej: get{return CalcularConsumo();}
        public int Consumo { get { return CalcularConsumo(); } set { } }
        //esta propiedad no es necesaria pero la clase esta obligada a implementarla
        public int CapacidadLitros { get; set; }
        public  int CalcularConsumo()
        {
            
            return 200;
        }
    }
```

Y ahora crearias una lista de IElectrodomesticos asi

```
List<IElectrodomestico> el = new List<IElectrodomestico>();
            el.Add(new Heladera() { CapacidadLitros = 1000, Nombre = "Heladera" });
            el.Add(new Heladera() { CapacidadLitros = 1000, Nombre = "Heladera" });
            el.Add(new Televisor() { Pulgadas = 40, Nombre = "Tele"  });
            dataGridView1.DataSource = el;
```

Para las propiedades que no estan inicializadas apareceria 0  (para tipo int) y vacio para los string en sus respectivas celdas del datagridview. Espero que te ayude.

ah y la propiedad AutoGenerateColumns de du datagridview deberia ser true para que todas las columnas aparezcan o especificar que propiedad debe mostrarse manualmente.